# How to enter a password in a batch?

Tags: batch-file

If I open the cmd and paste these 4 lines (the last one is an "Enter"):

```
cd "c:\Test"
cap staging deploy
123
```

it works, on the 2nd line, after a few seconds, the prompt asks for the password (123) but the "paste" did and the job started.
But if I do a batch it doesn't work, just wait to type in the password and I need to enter 123 and press enter.
How can I automatically put this password in a batch file?

thanks

Comment: This might work. `(echo 123)|cap staging deploy`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone, the solution to this that i find was use wscript to put the password, like this:

```
echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion & mode 150,32
cd "c:\Test"
set "_senha_=123"
set "_cmd_=cap staging deploy"

>"%temp%\_temp_file_4vbs_.vbs"^
    (
     echo/ Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject^("WScript.Shell"^)
     echo/ Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject^("WScript.Shell"^)
     echo/ StrPwd  = "!_senha_!"
     echo/ Wscript.Sleep 1000
     echo/ for j=1 To Len^(StrPwd^)
     echo/     x = Mid^(StrPwd,j,1^)
     echo/     WshShell.SendKeys x
     echo/     Wscript.Sleep 200
     echo/ Next 
     echo/ Wscript.Sleep 200
     echo/ WshShell.SendKeys "({ENTER})"
     ) 

set "_temp_vbs=%temp%\_temp_file_4vbs_.vbs" &  start "" /b !_cmd_!
@"%Windir%\System32\cScript.exe" //nologo "!_temp_vbs!" <nul & del /q /f "!_temp_vbs!" & goto :eof
```